# Combine 2 jQuery functions shorthand?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this:

```
$("#about-us .faq-cta").click(function () {
    $('#faq').load('faqs.html #main').delay(100).slideToggle('1000', "easeOutQuad", function () {
        $.waypoints('refresh');
        $("#siteNav li a").removeClass("siteNavSelected");
    }, {
        offset: function () {
            return $.waypoints('viewportHeight') - $(this).outerHeight();
        }
    });
});
```

And this:

```
if (window.location.hash.toLowerCase() === "#faq") {
    $("#about-us .faqCta").click(function () {
        $('#faq').load('faqs.html #main').delay(100).slideToggle('1000', "easeOutQuad", function () {
            $.waypoints('refresh');
            $("#siteNav li a").removeClass("siteNavSelected");
        }, {
            offset: function () {
                return $.waypoints('viewportHeight') - $(this).outerHeight();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Each do exactly the same thing.

Is there a way to write a bit of shorthand to combine the two?

Comment: If you're writing the same code more than once, it should probably be in its own function. In this case though, you're attaching an event listener, so I can't seem to see a reason you'd call it again if the hash matches. It's already there.

Comment: Does it matter if the event is handled when the IF is false? or does the .faqCta just not exist then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
var fcOnClick = function () {
    $('#faq').load('faqs.html #main').delay(100).slideToggle('1000', "easeOutQuad", function () {
        $.waypoints('refresh');
        $("#siteNav li a").removeClass("siteNavSelected");
    }, {
        offset: function () {
            return $.waypoints('viewportHeight') - $(this).outerHeight();
        }
    });
};

var $cont= $('#about-us');
$('.faq-cta',$cont).click(fcOnClick);
if(window.location.hash.toLowerCase() === "#faq"){
    $('.faqCta',$cont).click(fcOnClick);
}
```